# How to change the date in Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to be able to edit the dates within the $dates variable (Changing them in the function that generated them is not an option). Something like $dates->open->date = "change to example date"

```
    $dates = $this->FrameCalc(0);
    dd($dates);
```

Dump:

```
App\Frame {#1327
    -open: Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1525996800 {#1324
          date: 2018-05-11 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
     }
     -close: Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1527724799 {#1339
          date: 2018-05-30 23:59:59.0 UTC (+00:00)
   }
 }
```

Thanks,

Comment: `$dates->open = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('example date');`

Comment: in which format you want date?